# Joomla custom fields inside template

Tags: php, joomla

I would like to customize my template for Joomla 3.7 so that I can use the new feature of Joomla 3.7, Custom fields (com_fields), and display and format them via CSS in my template where I need to display them.

Can someone suggest me the PHP code I should use in the template to display field(s), some example please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

certainly not the right way to do it but I had the same need and I found a work around based on https://www.giudansky.com/news/12-coding/146-joomla-custom-fields

Copie default.php from /components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php to
 templates/YOUR_THEME/html/com_content/article/default.php

Add following code line 25 :

```
$myCustomFields = array();
    foreach($this->item->jcfields as $field) {
        $myCustomFields[$field->name] = $field->value;
    } 

$GLOBALS['myCustomFields'] = $myCustomFields;
```

Typically you put on a global var the content of fields attached to your article.
On your template page you can know retrieved value of your field.
just print_r($GLOBALS['myCustomFields']); to view the content of your array.

That will do the trick waiting for a better answer..

Answer (score 7):

For everyone getting late to the party. In case you want to use your custom form fields in a Module-Override (which really are the only way to modify j!-templates, so google 'joomla template override') you can use this handy snippet:

```
<?php
    JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
    $jcFields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article', $item, true);
    $itemCustomFields = array();
    foreach($jcFields as $field) {
        $itemCustomFields[$field->name] = $field->rawvalue;
    }
?>
```

Now you cna use your customfields like so: `itemCustomFields['customFieldName1']`

Haven't tested in article overrides. May soon, if so, this will get updated.

Answer (score 3):

This is absolutely the wrong way to do this I think but I was tearing my hair out so i came up with this quick db query to return custom field values in the template. surely this violates some kind of joomla protocol?
obviously this assumes you can get $articleid into your template already which is the Current ID of your article.

I too am waiting on a better solution but hope this helps

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();

$sql = "select * from #__fields_values where `item_id` = $articleid";                                                                            
$db->setQuery($sql);  
$fieldslist = $db->loadObjectList();

echo $fieldslist[0]->value;
echo $fieldslist[1]->value;
echo $fieldslist[your field ID here]->value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it was easiest to follow how com_fields does it in its rendering code. In Joomla!3.7+, you'll find it in **[joomla_root]/components/com_fields/layouts/fields/render.php**  .

Here are the main parts you need to reproduce the formatting that Joomla has:

```
JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
<dl class="fields-container">
<?php foreach ($this->item->jcfields as $field) : ?>
  <?php // If the value is empty do nothing ?>
  <?php if (!isset($field->value) || $field->value == '') : ?>
    <?php continue; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php $class = $field->params->get('render_class'); ?>
  <dd class="field-entry <?php echo $class; ?>">
    <?php echo FieldsHelper::render($context, 'field.render', array('field' => $field)); ?>
  </dd>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```

This loops through all available tags for the component or article. The nice thing about this method is it still applies the render classes you include with the fields.

*Make sure to set **Automatic Display** to **Do not automatically display** on your fields; otherwise you will see them twice on your page view.*

If you want to just target specific fields to show, you can use the name of the field to target it. (The label and value pair is underneath.) See [the field Joomla docs](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_custom_fields/Overrides#Loading_individual_fields) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this small function to get specific custom field values:

```
function getCustomFieldValue($field_name, $article_id, $default_value = '') {

  // Load custom field list
  $fields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article', $article_id, true);
  $field_ids = array_column($fields, 'id', 'name');
  $model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Field', 'FieldsModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
  
  // Return the value if the field exists, otherwise the default
  return array_key_exists($field_name, $field_ids) 
    ? $model->getFieldValue($field_ids[$field_name] , $article_id) 
    : $default_value;
  }
```

Usage:

```
$some_field_value = getCustomFieldValue('some-field-name', $some_article_id);
```

**Optimization:** I placed the function into a helper class, implemented the variables $fields, $field_ids and $model static and checked if they are already loaded to prevent redundant loading of the same data.